# How to set an observer for a url change in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Very simple question, I want to execute something when the url changes inside a custom element.

Currently I have:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    properties: {
        ...
    },
    listeners: {
        'playbutton.tap': 'playbuttonTap'
    },
    playbuttonTap: function(e) {
        document.getElementById('playbutton').style.display = "none";
    },
    observers: [
        '_routePageChanged()'
    ],
    _routePageChanged: function() {
        console.log('STOP MOVIE')
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Your `_routePageChanged` observer isn't actually observing a property...

I suggest adding an element to watch the address bar, like [`<app-route>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-route):

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
```

Then you can watch for any changes to the `route.path` property like so:

```
observers: [
  '_routeChanged(route.path)'
]
```

Comment: Is there a way to detect route change without using Polymer? I am writing a Chrome Extension that should run some code whenever URL changes, but it looks like Polymer somehow magically updates the URL without firing `window.onload`, `window.beforeunload`, or using `window.history.pushState`, `window.history.replaceState` functions. The app in question is using `<app-route>`. Is there an event that I can listen to or function that I can wrap to detect URL changes?